# c# selenium accessing\clicking tab item

Tags: c#, selenium

[image: cannot click thi button]

tried both:

```
Driver.FindElement(By.Name(""));
Driver.FindElement(By.Id(""));
```

Comment: hi @OriCohen please write question properly along with code that you have tried.
You need to modify your question.Bcoz we are not getting actually what you need and what is your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You might be writing wrong syntax,

```
Driver.FindElement(By.Name("HERE_YOUR_NAME_OF_ELEMENT"));
```

HERE_YOUR_NAME_OF_ELEMENT but you are trying to put again get element by ID `Driver.FindElement(By.Id("HERE_YOUR_ID_OF_ELEMENT"));`

and also you missplaced the `;` inside `By.Name(";")`

please go through syntax and try to rewrite your program again.

i can see there is  tag so you can click on it

```
elem1= driver1.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@class='ATTRIBUTE_VALUE']"); 
elem1.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[@ATTRIBUTE_NAME='ATTRIBUTE_VALUE']").click();
```

Comment: Hi it’s not a syntax problem if I wasn’t clear..problem is to locate element id/name  inside tab menu and access it. Working with chrome driver

Comment: yeah you should really learn some html basics if you want to be able to use any of this sort of thing.

Comment: I am able to click other elements on this page, just not the ones inside the tab menu..

Comment: hello @OriCohen would you like to share your html dom of tabs for more idea about your issue thanks

Comment: your answers were not professional. solved it by myself using the correct xpath

Comment: @OriCohen Yeah great you can  modify my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think this is helpful for you.
You can use `FirefoxDriver` (or `ChromeDriver` as per your question)

```
WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
Actions oAction= new Actions(driver);

oAction.MoveToElement(YOUR_ELEMENT).Click().Perform();
```